# How to synchronize global variable Java

Tags: android, global-variables, synchronize

```
String compBut1 = "D0", compBut2 = "D0", compBut3 = "D0", playaBut1 = "D0", playaBut2 = "D0", playaBut3 = "D0";  

public void changeOver()
{
    String[] set = {playaBut2, playaBut3, playaBut1};
    int butPos = Arrays.asList(set).indexOf(positions[posOld]);
    set[butPos] = positions[posNew];
}
```

What must i do to ensure that whenever the value of variables in the array set are changed the global variable also get changed. I can see in the debugger that when I am inside the method the value get changed but as soon as i go out the change is discarded.

Comment: Can you explain a bit clearly? Which variables do you want to sync?

Comment: Well. the array set contains grobal variables. Each of those variables are global variables. What I am trying to do is, if i change that variable in the array set then thoughout that class, the value of that global variable must change as well. say, i change playaBut1 in array set in that method, then the value of that global variable must also remain changed when i leave that method.

Comment: No, you are actually not changing `playBut1`. If `set[2]=playBut1` and if you assign `set[2]=newString` you are just changing `set[2]` and value of `playBut1` will not be changed. If you assign `playBut1 = something`, then only it will change.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] set = {playaBut2, playaBut3, playaBut1};
```

You think the above stores references to the respective strings so that whenever any of these strings is changed, the referenced string changes.

However, what it actually does is copies the values to new instances of String and makes an array of them. Java doesn't allow you to store references (pointers a la C/C++) for safety reasons.

What you should do is: make an array of the globally declared strings and change them directly inside your function.

```
String[] compBut={"D0","D0","D0"};
String[] playaBut={"D0","D0","D0"};

public void changeOver(){
  int butPos = Arrays.asList(playaBut).indexOf(positions[posOld]);
  playaBut[butPos] = positions[posNew];
}
```